how to upgrade AKS cluster with custom CA certificate without failure
Hello AKS/k8s experts,
Our traffic for AKS goes via our NVA Firewall which expects a custom CA to send the traffic. We have implemented this: Custom certificate authority (CA) in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) (preview) - Azure Kubernetes Service and it seems to work.
If I want to upgrade the nodes/nodepool - Will the updates/upgrades fail since it will try and spin up a new node which may fail due to not having the certificate? If yes- whats the best practice or way to avoid upgrade failure?
